# Find out the count of the common values in two list using excel formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have lists in column A and B. There are values that are common and i want to find the count of the common values using the excel formula

```
 A     B
10    20
 5    30
30    35
20    42
52    50
```

Here two values common are 30 and 20. So, count of common value will be 2. 
The list may contain text or numeric values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No problem, `COUNTIF` accepts array criteria and `SUMPRODUCT` will add them up for you

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A1:A5,B1:B5))
```

This returns `2` with your sample data, as required